# StepIndex with wrong value

Tags: jquery, smart-wizard

On first initializing of smartWizard, I get stepIndex of NULL of showStep event. But, I would expect this to be 0 or whatever is set in 'selected'.

When I click next, it will log index 0 instead of 1 and so on.

I am sure I am doing something wrong, but cant figure this one out.

```
$('#smartwizard').smartWizard({
 selected: 0,
 theme: 'arrows',
 enableURLhash: false,
 toolbarSettings: {
 showPreviousButton: false,
 toolbarPosition: 'bottom'
 },
 anchorSettings: {
 anchorClickable: false, // Enable/Disable anchor navigation
 },
 });

 $('#smartwizard').on("showStep", function(e, anchorObject, stepIndex, stepDirection) {
    console.log(stepIndex);
  });


});
```

Comment: Is smartWizardm a typo?

Comment: haha Yeah of course